# Liquibase not executing changeset on H2 DB when precondition exists (tableexists)

Tags: h2, liquibase

In first change set table  tb_transformation is already created. Below is the 4th changeset where i insert extra column to table when precondition passes. But its not executing the changeset. When i remove precondition and execute its inserting successfully.

```
<changeSet id="2020-03-004-add-columns-to-tb_transformation" author="TAAS">
    <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
            <tableExists tableName="TB_TRANSFORMATION"/>
    </preConditions>
    <addColumn tableName="TB_TRANSFORMATION">
        <column name="MARKET_INFRASTRUCTURE" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </addColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there some environments where the table might not exist? If not, and everything is being 'controlled' by Liquibase, then you should just be able to remove the precondition.

Comment: Yes. Junits are executed on H2 embedded DB. Database is created from scratch each time the junit module is executed. But table is created in first changeset only. According to documentation i believe liquibase should have committed the table to db after first changelog is executed. I expect table to be existing in db when am executing above mentioned changeset. But the precondition fails. I guess this is an issue .

Comment: I work on the Liquibase project. If you can put together a minimal repro case and submit an issue at https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues I can make sure it gets addressed.